# How do I check if a Rails.application.config variable is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Even though `Rails.application.config.trackable_models` returns a full array, `defined?(Rails.application.config.trackable_models)` returns nil.

```
Rails.application.config.trackable_models # => ["NewsItem", "ContentPage", "Event"]
defined?(Rails.application.config.trackable_models): # => nil
```

Setting a local variable in the same way is fine:

```
foo = ["x"]
defined?(foo) # => local-variable
```

What is the proper way to check for the existence of a config variable if not "defined?"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check the method is defined in the literal sense, use `respond_to`

```
Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:trackable_models)
```

If you want to check if the method returns something other than `nil`, you have some options:

```
tm = Rails.application.config.trackable_models
tm.nil?
tm.presence || 'default value'
tm.present?
tm.blank?
```

Comment: Thanks @steel... `respond_to?` works perfect. The rest is useful assuming trackable_models is defined, otherwise any call to `Rails.applications.config.trackable_models` result in "undefined method 'trackable_models'"